# Using 'ESNext' as a TypeScript lib option screws up the react testing library 'screen' types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, react-testing-library

This seems like a super obscure bug, but not sure where I would look for it in issues.

[Repro for this here.](https://github.com/dwjohnston/esnext-rtl/tree/master)

I have what looks like a conventional React+RTL+TypeScript+Jest setup.

However, if I'm using `ESNext` in the `lib` option of the `tsconfig.json`, then I get this error, (in VSCode only, the test still runs fine).

```
userEvent.click(screen.getByText('aaaa'));
```

```
Argument of type '"aaaa"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectorMatcherOptions | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

If I remove ESnext from the lib folder, and restart, then it works fine.

Is this a bug, in which case which Github issue tracks it? (Is this an issue with TypeScript or VSCode?)

Otherwise, why is happening, and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is really interesting question. From my understanding, the issue isn't from `esnext` lib. The real issue is from missing `DOM` library instead.

If you deeply look at the definition of `screen` method, you would see the following definition for each method:

```js
export type BoundFunction<T> = T extends (
    attribute: string,
    element: HTMLElement,
    text: infer P,
    options: infer Q,
) => infer R
    ? (text: P, options?: Q) => R
    : T extends (a1: any, text: infer P, options: infer Q, waitForElementOptions: infer W) => infer R
    ? (text: P, options?: Q, waitForElementOptions?: W) => R
    : T extends (a1: any, text: infer P, options: infer Q) => infer R
    ? (text: P, options?: Q) => R
    : never;
```

- In case having no `DOM`, `tsc` will infer the 1st result `(text: P, options?: Q) => R` since it looks like having no idea what is `HTMLElement`.
- In case of having `DOM`, `tsc` will know your input `aaa` as string which is not `HTMLElement`, so it infers the 2nd result: `(text: P, options?: Q, waitForElementOptions?: W) => R`. That's why it works.

In short, as long as you specify `DOM` as part of your `lib` then it would work as expected:

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"]
}
```

Comment: Glad you think so. This is the most offended I've been about a downvote here. :D

Comment: I've been able to reproduce your solution in my example. Why is that if you leave the lib option complete off it works? Does Typescript add DOM by default?

Comment: Here is the default `lib` addressed: `For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost, For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost `. Most cases `DOM` is added by default.

Comment: How did you find this out? Can you post a link?

Comment: Ah. You can reference to its official website https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html